# Where can I buy an electric immersion heater in Madrid, Spain

Tags: power, madrid

I am currently in Madrid for my job, and I badly need an electric immersion heater for having tea/coffee in my hostel room.

I have seen these are available online, but I cannot order from there since I cannot pay online.

Can anyone please tell me where I can buy such immersion heaters and if at all they are available offline in shops and how much would that cost?

Comment: Is there any particular reason it has to be an immersion heater and can't just be a kettle? The kettle should be easier to get by.

Comment: Well a kettle will also do, but it has to be an electric one because I got no gas stove here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An electric jug will do most things better than an immersion heater in your case.

If you can to minimise water used be sure that the coil of the element face downwards towards bottom of the jug. As long as the water is say 5mm above the parts of the element that get hot it will work well. You may be able to have a small part of the hot portion above water as it will be "heat sunk" by the underwater part.

If you really want an immersion heater and cannot find one you can make one from a jug + element. In many cases you can unscrew the element and remove it then add part of the cord socket to it. How easy this is will vary with design. Dropping the element plus cord into water when live is "not recommended".

Some (hopefully few) immersion heaters are so flimsy as to be dangerous.
Inspect carefully. 
Be aware of what aspects of use are potentially dangerous or lethal.

**Semi-related:** I stayed in a Chinese hotel where the hot water temperature was so low that a decent bath could not be had (maybe 30C?). I like to soak in a hot bath when facilities allow to offset the effects of overdoing things the rest of the time. I bought an immersion heater and used it to raise the temperature of a bathful of hot water to something more acceptable. (DO NOT introduce ANY part of your body to bath water while doing this!!!. ). Inspection  of the heater showed that the chance of it not electrocuting somebody long term in its intended role was "low". I dealt with the heater with extreme prejudice" before binning it on departure. 'Let no man heat with thee hereafter'.

Comment: Thanks Russel! Can you please tell me where I can get one and how much it would cost? I am planning to get an electric jug/kettle since all I would be doing is heating water, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can find Kettle (or electric jug) in many stores (El Corte ingles, FNAC) in Spanish the name is "Hervidor de agua"

http://www.fnac.es/Bodum-Bistro-Hervidor-de-agua-11451-294-Color-Rojo-Desayuno-Cafe-Accesorios-para-el-desayuno-Expresso-y-cafeteras/a839940

P.S. I posted a link to the item as an exmaple, but it can be purchased on person in the store.

Comment: Thanks SERPRO. How much would it cost approx? I am looking to buy a cheaper one.

Comment: I found online as cheap as 15 Euros: http://www.milanuncios.com/anuncios/hervidor-agua.htm but I don't know in the street